# How do i stop simulating rigid bodies past a certain point?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I just started using blender last week and I've been messing around with physics simulations. Right now I'm using Magicavoxel assets for a destruction simulation and I noticed that a lot of parts fall off the edge of the plane and fall into the void. My question is how can I stop simulating the objects once they get past a certain point. It feels like a waste of processing power to calculate the physics for hundreds of cubes that will never be seen.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just uncheck the *dynamic* checkbox for the frame, where you want to stop it.

For the frame before, check the *dynamic* checkbox.

Tap <kbd>I</kbd> on your keyboard while hovering over that checkbox for both keyframes.

[image]

Comment: Thankyou I think that'll work. Also how can I do this for all of the cubes I have selected? When I tried it only applied the keyframes to one cube.

Comment: you can try the ctrl-l functionality, with which you can copy settings to lots of other objects